# Apache server ..Waiting ....for 40 seconds occasionally

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a apache 2.4, php, mysql based web application. The application works like charm most of the time with 40ms response times. Already performance tuned with apache cache, php's opcache and apache mod_deflate.

However rarely once every 2 hours or so...when I invoke the application on a browser...it hangs saying waiting ..... for few seconds say 40 seconds or so...and then picks up back to super speed.

what do you think could be possible reasons?

Just for information. it's all localhost. and there is no network.

Comment: Which service you are using? Most of the cases if server is not used for a time then temporarily service is down for cost budget like Google Compute Engine does it.

Comment: You can use the mod_status to take a look at the workers status. Maybe the problem is occuring on connection prepare or ssl init.  [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html)

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I had this on a windows machine once or twice. Changing 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in the mysql connection helped for me.

Comment: It's most probably OS issue. A lot of programs share your memory and have different priority of execution. So when something with higher priority runs in the same time as server service needed to complete your operation delays are possible, especially when service turns from idle to active status (which requires some amount of memory to be allocated again). As soon as enough memory becomes available everything continues to work as charm. Mostly antivirus software, torrent clients, skype, etc. cause this issue so try to stop everything you don't need when working with apache.